# JQuery UI sortable in a scrollable container - scroll position "jumps" when sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Please check this almost identical question first: [jQuery Sortable List - scroll bar jumps up when sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735372/jquery-sortable-list-scroll-bar-jumps-up-when-sorting)

I have exactly the same problem, only that I tried all the suggested solutions there with no luck

**Here is the way to reproduce**

- create a [sortable list](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/)
- have it scrollable
- scroll down
- reorder items
- scroll position "jumps" up

**Here is the code (see also in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gwen4/1/))**

**Html**

```
<ul id="panel" class="scroll">
    <li class="content" style="background-color:red">item1</li>
    <li class="content" style="background-color:green">item2</li>
    <li class="content" style="background-color:blue">item3</li>
    <li class="content" style="background-color:gray">item4</li>
    <li class="content" style="background-color:yellow">item5</li>    
</ul>​
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
    $("#panel").sortable({
        items: ".content",
        forcePlaceholderSize: true
    }).disableSelection();
    $(".content").disableSelection();

});​
```

**CSS**

```
.scroll{
    overflow: scroll;
    border:1px solid red;
    height: 200px;
    width: 150px;
}
.content{
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}
​
```

Here is the code (in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fnncs/3/)) after trying the notion of the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735372/jquery-sortable-list-scroll-bar-jumps-up-when-sorting/4735975#4735975) (with no luck)

I can try to understand why it happens (list get's "shortened" for a quick second), but all attempts to use placeholders or helpers to avoid it didn't work either. I feel I tried almost any permutation of the "scrollable" options with no luck

**Browsers I tried**

IE9, Firefox 10.0.1, and Chrome 17

**JQuery versions**

core 1.7.1, UI v 1.8.17

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a solution? Could it be a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you modifiy your CSS for the `.scroll` element by adding:

```
position:relative;
```

That should resolve this issue.

Comment: Nice! it solved the issue for the bottom most item, but there seems to be still an issue with the others. http://jsfiddle.net/Fnncs/4/

Answer (score 2):

Adding `overflow-y:scroll` to the sortable list even without the `height` property solved it for me. It only shows a disabled scrollbar, but that's okay.

Answer (score 2):

아래로 스크롤 할때 는 이런식으로 하면 됩니다.

```
var cY = -1;
var base = 0;
$("").sortable({
  sort: function(event, ui) {
    var nextCY = event.pageY;
    if(cY - nextCY < -10){
      if(event.clientY + ui.helper.outerHeight(true) - 20 > document.body.clientHeight) {
        base = base === 0 ? event.clientY : base;
        var move = event.clientY - base;
        var curScrollY = $(document).scrollTop();
        $(document).scrollTop(curScrollY + move+3);
        base = event.clientY;
      }
    }
  },
  // .....
});
```

Comment: The problem is very clear. You have written the answer in non-English language.

Comment: because of i can't write english.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like *jQuery UI 1.9.2* solved the issue.

If you are unable to change the library, there's a workaround including a simple scroll bar operation. The idea is simple:

- Keep the previous scroll position every time you scroll.
- Set scroll back to the previous position when you start dragging your element.

Here you go;

```
var lastScrollPosition = 0; //variables defined in upper scope
var tempScrollPosition = 0;

window.onscroll = function () { // Up to you requirement you may change it to another elemnet e.g $("#YourPanel").onscroll
    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
    $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function () {
        tempScrollPosition = lastScrollPosition; // Scrolls don't change from position a to b. They cover some numbers between a and b during the change to create a smooth sliding visual. That's why we pick the previous scroll position with a timer of 250ms.
    }, 250));

    lastScrollPosition = $(document).scrollTop(); // Up to you requirement you may change it to another elemnet e.g $("#YourPanel").onscroll
};

$("#YourSortablePanel").sortable({
    start: function (event, ui) {
        $(document).scrollTop(tempScrollPosition);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the height of the container changing when sorting (just before the placeholder is created)

The problem is well described and answered in this stack overflow : https://stackoverflow.com/a/32477389/2604980

Answer (score 0):

For me this sortable options were working if you don't want to remove overflow css from body:

```
    start(e, ui) {
      if (fixOffset) ui.item.css('transform', `translateY(${document.body.scrollTop}px)`);
      fixOffset = true;
    },
    change(e, ui) {
      ui.item.css('transform', `translateY(${document.body.scrollTop}px)`);
    },
    stop(e, ui) {
      ui.item.css('transform', 'translateY(0)');
    },
```